# Downsampling in MATLAB - why scaling filter coefficients?

Tags: filters, audio, finite-impulse-response, downsampling, resampling

Trying to undertsand how MATLAB does resampling, looking at `toolbox/signal/resample.m`.

This is the part where (downsampling) filter coefficients are calculated:

```
  fc = 1/2/pqmax;
  L = 2*N*pqmax + 1;
  h = firls( L-1, [0 2*fc 2*fc 1], [1 1 0 0]).*kaiser(L,bta)' ;
  h = p*h/sum(h);
```

(In this case `pqmax` and `p` both represent downsampling ratio.)

Not sure what is the purpose of last line where all filter coefficients are scaled by **downsampling ratio over coeffs sum**, `p/sum(h)`? Does anyone know the theory behind?

MATLAB [firls](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/firls.html)
MATLAB [kaiser](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/kaiser.html)
`firls` theory: [Least Squared Error Design of FIR Filters](https://cnx.org/contents/f6YHBsDY@3/Least-Squared-Error-Design-of-)

Comment: Related to [FIR filter gain](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4693/fir-filter-gain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done to achieve unity gain, i.e. to have the same energy in the downsampled and original signal.

The sum of filter coefficients `sum(h)` is the filter gain, by dividing the filter by it, it is set to 1 (unity). 
It is multiplied by `p` to compensate for the missing samples, again to achieve the same engery as in the original signal.